How to rotate a figure's camera by a rotation matrix
Here's my starting set of vectors representing a local coordinate frame:

Starting point

Using some arbitrary rotation matrix, I rotate them in 3D:

Standard visual outcome after rotation by R

However, I'd like to keep the RGB vectors visually fixed and rotate the camera viewpoint such that the resulting image shows the world coordinate system rotated relative to the local coordinate frame:

Desired visual outcome after rotation by R

How would I do that programatically, using the rotation matrix (and thus being able to find Euler angles, quaternions, or an axis-angle representation, if necessary)?

Strange downvote, without explaining why. One might suspect a link between this and the commenter below who gave demonstrably wrong code and is being argumentative about it. It's always a shame to see personalities collide with code.

First, assign a variable for the axis handle:
h = gca;

Then, you can manipulate the View property (azimuth and elevation).
For example, to get a flat view of X,Y axes, set:
h.View = [0 90]

If this is not enough, you can also control the cameraPosition property.
Refer also to the following documentation:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/defining-scenes-with-camera-graphics.html

Thanks for giving it a shot, but that doesn't work. All you can do with view is rotate the camera view along two axes, which is not enough for the full 3D transformation. Try it yourself and you'll see.

@KennSebesta You haven't read my entire answer. Did you try to modify the property of cameraPosition? Try to change it in the opposite direction of the object. It has 3 DOF.

I read the entire answer and tried the code you listed. As pointed out, view() rotates along two axes. This is reflected in the code itself, which takes a 2D, not 3D, vector. Those are azimuth and elevation, which does not include any scene roll.

Too bad that you still don't read the entire answer, and don't respect the effort of others to help you. Please remove your vote down for both answers. Did you try to modify the property of cameraPosition, as mentioned in my answer?

I'm sorry this is rubbing you the wrong way, but I examined the code and it was wrong. You made a claim as to how to do something, you supported that claim with code, and the code didn't work as promised. It failed to deliver the requested viewpoint, and indeed cannot as view() is strictly limited to elevation and azimuth. The rest of the documentation isn't useful, as at best it contradicts your answer. Consider how this answer will look to search engines which try to quickly steer people with similar questions to the answer. It's good practice to downvote categorically wrong things.

The hgtranform() API can be used to transform a graphics object. It can rotate, scale and translate graphics objects, more detailed discussion on the allowed and disallowed operations can be found here. Here is an example:
s = surf(peaks(20));
h = hgtransform();
set(s, 'parent', h);
h.Matrix = makehgtform("xrotate", pi/2);

This should rotate the surface plot by Pi/2 radians about the Z- axis. You can control the axis and angle of rotation by modifying the inputs to makehgtform().

Thanks for giving this a try. The question is not about rotating the plotted data object, it's about rotating the plotting axes. Running your code, it's clear that this does the former and not the latter.
